# TemplateBinding to Parent's Content which is itself bound to an XPath - Content Not Showing

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, styles

I have an ItemsControl whose ItemsSource is bound to an XML data provider. The code looks like this.

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Margin="30"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource VideosXML}, 
              XPath=TutorialVideo}" >
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Button Style="{StaticResource StyleMetroVideoButton}" 
              Content="{Binding XPath=@Name}"
              ToolTip="{Binding XPath=Description}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                        
</ItemsControl>
```

VideosXML is an XML data provider referencing an external XML file. As you can see the Name attributes apply to the buttons' content and the Description elements in the xml file apply to the tooltips of the buttons. Below is the code for the button's style. It basically is a textblock with a faded "Play" button over the top of it.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="StyleMetroVideoButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid Name="PlayGrid" Background="#FF323236">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Image Name="Play" Source="{StaticResource BtnVideoPlayHoverPNG}"  Opacity="0.0" Stretch="None"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.6" TargetName="Play"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#8D8D94" TargetName="PlayGrid"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource BtnVideoPlayClickPNG}" TargetName="Play"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.6" TargetName="Play"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#8D8D94" TargetName="PlayGrid"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.0" TargetName="Play"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="90" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5"/>
    </Style>
```

You can see from the style that the "Text" in the TextBlock is bound to the content of the button itself: Text="{TemplateBinding Content}", and from the first piece of code the Content of the button is bound to an XML element via XPath. However, no text is shown at all. It works if I hard code something in the button like Content="A Button" will show. Also the tooltip is working fine so I know its reading data from the XML file. So what makes binding to XPath different than hard coding a value?

Thanks in advance for looking at my question!

**EDIT**: Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Videos xmlns="">
  <TutorialVideo Name="Video 1">
    <Description>A video to watch</Description>
    <Filepath>video1.wmv</Filepath>
  </TutorialVideo>
</Videos>
```

Comment: what happens if you replace `TextBlock` with `ContentPresenter` (just guessing) if you post a small xml example I can have a look.

Comment: Nothing seemed to change when adding the ContentPresenter. I put some sample xml up. Thanks!

Comment: it works if you use this on the TextBlock `Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}"` so it seems the content passed is the whole xml element, I will keep looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem, for some reason the `Content` property is passing the whole xml element, setting the Content binding to `Content="{Binding XPath=@Name, Path=Value}"` should fix the issue

There is probably a logical explaination for this, Google will know

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Margin="30"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource VideosXML}, 
              XPath=TutorialVideo}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource StyleMetroVideoButton}"  
                            Content="{Binding XPath=@Name, Path=Value}"  
                            ToolTip="{Binding XPath=Description}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Oh okay, thanks! Hmmm it is working; however, the content that is shown is the Button's Content itself. I can delete the whole TextBlock from the style and it will still show because the Content is not being passed to the Text of the TextBlock. The reason that I needed this is because the TextBlock can wrap text, the button cant.

Comment: Updated answer, it seems if you set the Binding path to Value it works fine, I thing it has to do with the ContentPresenter not know you want the string value of the xml element,.

Comment: Nice! I appreciate the help. I'm not trying to nitpick, but now both the Button Content and TextBlock Text show and overlap. Maybe I'm approaching this idea the wrong way ???. I put the TextBlock as the Button Content and that works; however, that does not give me the felexibility of having it in the style anymore... Sorry I'm still learning xaml and how it works.